# How to get data with field names from txt file to use for Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Trying to read data from a txt file that has data staggered with field names in the first row and identifier names in the first and last three columns. I'm not sure how I could go about this when it comes to graphing the data as well as saving the field names and identifier names in arrays.

Example of text file data:

```
Field 1   Field 2   Field 3    
name1     6         FGT123    
name2     7         FRE356    
name3     8         VDE321   
name4     9         RXW432     
name5     10        LWE143
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python and pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',sep=' ') # space as a separator
```

After the data is in dataframe you can use matplotlib to make your plots.

First you need to edit your textfile. Headers cannot have spaces if you use that as a separator in your textfile. So you need to rename headers as Field1 Field2 Field3.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, I was told to use numpy. Would panda be better? I was searching before and saw some use of panda as well.

Comment: In pandas library there is a function named read_csv which is easy to use. (as in above example) Just one-liner to read whole file.

Comment: What happens if there is multiple spaces? Not just in the headers, but even between my data. Should I just reformat the entire txt file to match for sep=' '?

Comment: Usually you use separator like , or ; A character that you do not have anywhere else in the file, it is dedicated to separate fields. If you have many spaces it does not seam to work correctly. So please reformat the file if you have multiple spaces between fields, and if you wish you can change the character to something else like sep=';' or sep=',' and edit your text file accordingly.